# Symfony 4 autowire not working with root namespaces

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

On standard there is everything put under `App` namespace.
So if I will have such structure with `TestController` having `public function xxx(TestInterface $test);` everything works as should.

```
-src
 -Core
  -TestInterface (App\Core)
 -Api
  -Controller
   -TestController (App\Api\Controller)
 -Domain
  -Service
   -TestService implements TestInterface (App\Domain\Service)
```

Now the problem is my project does not have `App` prefix.
My structure looks like this:

```
-src
 -Core
  -TestInterface (Core)
 -Api
  -Controller
   -TestController (Api\Controller)
 -Domain
  -Service
   -TestService implements TestInterface (Domain\Service)
```

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
```

**services.yaml**

```
Core\:
    resource: '../src/Core/*'
    exclude: '../src/Core/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

Domain\:
    resource: '../src/Domain/*'
    exclude: '../src/Domain/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

Api\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Api/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

The most funny part of this is that almost everything works good, including dependency injection as long as I use direct class namespaces. Only finding by interface doesn't work.

**This works:**
`public function xxx(TestService $test)`

**This doesn't work:**
`public function xxx(TestInterface $test)`

**Here is the error:**

> Cannot resolve argument $test of
>   "Api\Controller\TestController::xxx()":
>       Cannot autowire service ".service_locator.EcpiaYx": it references interface "Core\TestInterface" but no such service exists.
>       You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "Domain\TestService" service.

Comment: Just experienced the same problem. It's funny the container knows exactly the only service that implements that interface and suggests to create an alias for it but does not auto-wire it itself :-S

Comment: Why would even container bother about methods inside my services that are not __construct ? Whats wrong there?